# MongoDB filter array element in a nested object

Tags: mongodb

I have a document as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56423b2558cb340599108b35"),
    "test" : {
        "source" : [
            {
                "member" : "abc"
            },
            {
                "member" : "xyz"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to filter on the array element xyz, and I am trying the following query:

db.coll.find({ "test.source.member" : "xyz" }, { "test.source.$.member" : true }).pretty()

Apparently it used to work on 2.4, on 2.6 it does not work,

On 2.4 it returned the "xyz", whereas on 2.6 it returns "abc" i.e. the first element. Is there a way to filter "abc" because eventually i want to update. BTW, i also tried with $elemMatch and it seems to give the same output "abc".

Thanks.

Comment: The posted 'code' is definitely not C, so please remove the 'c' tag

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/projection/positional/#project-array-documents), if you are running 2.6, this should give you the correct output:

```
db.coll.find({ "test.source.member" : "xyz"}, { "test.source.$" : 1}).pretty()
```

You could extract the member by doing this:

```
var member = db.coll.find(
                 { "test.source.member" : "xyz"},
                 { "test.source.$" : 1}
                 ).test.source[0].member;
```

The value of member would be:

```
xyz
```

Comment: Same as before. does not show the correctly filtered item.

Comment: @user2766839 when you run db.version() what does it output in mongo shell?

Comment: @inspired, shouldn't it be { "test.source.$" : 1 } instead of { "test.source.$.member" : 1 } in order to get only the first element from the source array that has member "xyz"? If no, can you please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: I tried inserting a fresh query and then the filtering works. However after upgrade the filtering does not seem to work in other records. Currently investigating that.

Comment: @LisaGagarina, you are right `test.source.$` is correct, but when i tested `test.source.$.member` I didn't get an error. Thanks, I'll update it

Comment: @user2766839 can you post sample documents when you run `db.coll.find()`

Comment: The posted 'code' is definitely not C, so please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: @user3629249 you may want to add that comment to the OP's question, so he can see it